# Using to WHERE clauses in select statement

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am try to create a statement to retrieve column1 where column2 = "0" and column3 = "1", and I also want it to retrieve from column1 where column3 = "0" and column2 = "1".

This is my select statement, but its not working. I am not sure of what clause to use for the second WHERE.

```
string insertSql = @"SELECT Status from User_friend 
                    WHERE (ProfileId1 = @FriendProfileId)
                    AND (ProfileId = 
                        (SELECT ProfileId 
                         FROM User_Profile 
                         WHERE UserId = @UserId))
                    OR 
                        WHERE (ProfileId = @FriendProfileId) 
                        AND (ProfileId1 = 
                            (SELECT ProfileId 
                             FROM User_Profile 
                             WHERE UserId = @UserId))";
```

Comment: What for all this C# code if you are having problems only with SQL statement? Showing irrelevant code waters down your question and makes it harder to understand it.

Comment: And what is strange syntax `some condition THEN WHERE another condition` in your SQL query? How do you suppose it to work?

Comment: Andy, i am not really sure of how to include the other where in the main statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call me crazy, but i think you're just looking for the 'OR' operator...

```
        string insertSql = @"SELECT Status from User_friend 
                WHERE ((ProfileId1 = @FriendProfileId)
                AND (ProfileId = 
                    (SELECT ProfileId 
                     FROM User_Profile 
                     WHERE UserId = @UserId))) OR
                ((ProfileId = @FriendProfileId) 
                    AND (ProfileId1 = 
                        (SELECT ProfileId 
                         FROM User_Profile 
                         WHERE UserId = @UserId)))";
```

Comment: you are not crazy, u just made my day Thanks Alot